# Does it make sense to catch ThreadAbortException and perform no action?

Tags: .net, exception

```
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{ }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    TraceManager.TraceException(ex,
                                (int)ErrorCode.GENERIC_EXCEPTION,
                                ex.StackTrace + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + VendorUrl);
}
```

does it make sense to even have the

```
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{ }
```

or will that cause the `ThreadAbortException` to be swallowed and lost forever?

Comment: `ThreadAbortException` will get rethrown at the completion of the handler.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`ThreadAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) cannot be caught "completely"; it will automatically be rethrown at the end of the `catch` block (see the linked MSDN docs page) *unless* [`Thread.ResetAbort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort.aspx) is called first.

So, the only sensible `catch` block would be:

```
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
    // possibly do something here
    Thread.ResetAbort();
}
```

But this has a really evil smell. There's probably no reason to do it, so you may want to rethink your approach.

**Update:**
There are many questions on SO that deal with `Thread.Abort`:

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2251964/50079) has the same answer as I have given here.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/421389/50079) has an answer that expands on "don't ever call `Thread.Abort` unless Cthulhu is rising" (which I toned down considerably to an "evil smell").

There are also many others.

Comment: +1 : Wording nit-pick.  It can be caught -- it will just be re-thrown.

Comment: @Hogan: reworded that a bit; now the meaning should be more clear.

Comment: Very nice answer.  I'd give it another +1 if I could.

Answer (score 5):

The ThreadAbortException can't be caught like that.  It will get rethrown automatically at the end of the catch block unless you call Thread.ResetAbort();

Having a catch block as you have here for ThreadAbortException allows it to be auto-rethrown without the catch(Exception) block attempting to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Thread.Abort` on a thread effectively sets a flag which will cause a `ThreadAbortException` to be thrown any time code isn't processing that exception nor associated `finally` blocks.  Catching the exception without calling `Thread.ResetAbort()` will simply result in the runtime throwing another `ThreadAbortException` at its next opportunity.  Such behavior is not completely meaningless, however, since it will cause all inner `finally` blocks to run to completion before the exception can be seen by outer exception-filter blocks.   Whether or not that is a good thing will depend upon the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something specific for different kind of exceptions then it makes since to have seperate catch blocks. Otherwise you can just use the one Exception catch

Comment: I disagree. It's usually better to be specific about what you're catching. I think that if you don't know what kinds of exceptions your "try" block might throw, it means you haven't given your application enough testing.

Answer (score -3):

It will be caught and lost.  You should really only be catching exceptions that you can do something with or that you log and then rethrow (with throw; not throw new [some exception];).