# Disabling .net error loging event viewer application

Tags: c#, .net

do you know if there's a way to disable an app console written on C# from writing on app event viewer? The app is a ftp sync I downloaded from http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=706&lngWId=10

The app event viewer shows the error: ".NET Runtime 2.0 Error -> EventType clr20r3, P1 enviaxml.exe, P2 1.0.4643.32868, P3 505784e9, P4 ftpautobackup, P5 1.0.4643.32868, P6 505784e9, P7 1, P8 2ec, P9 system.threading.threadabort, P10 NIL."

The main sub is inside a try catch... so I dont know why it's writing the error.

Do you know how to disable it? Thanks

Comment: Your error message would suggest that the system is throwing a ThreadAbortException. For more info see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651589/does-it-make-sense-to-catch-threadabortexception-and-perform-no-action

Answer (score 0):

This propable means that the error / exception is occurring before your program starts i.e during the time your're program is loaded by the CLR. Hence you never get a chance to catch the exception