# how to stop current process of C# application and start another function

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am explaining my scenario, i have a function which print 1 to 10000 while printing i have to stop the process and let user know the current i value and if user presses enter it should continue again.

i am using

```
if ((Console.KeyAvailable) && (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))
```

but it doesn,t work, to complicate my task i am using threads, even if i manage to break this thread, child thread starts executing, i just want to stop the entire execution process for a moment and execute another function.

Comment: you can work with WaitHandles like ManualResetEvents - it's not really that difficult

Comment: can you give any links regarding WaitHandles,

Comment: my whileloop is similar to this while(count!=0){if ((Console.KeyAvailable) && (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))break; function_temp();  } in function temp i have started a new thread.

Comment: You should probably show a bit more code, what you want to do should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [the `BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), specifically, how to implement cancellation.

You'll basically need to check inside the loop if a cancellation is pending.  If it is, then exit the loop.

Comment: Another couple tutorials on `BackgroundWorker`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/BackgroundWorker_Threads.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your using Threads. You can use this kind of code..

```
// Start
thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(YourCommand));
thread.Start();

// Pause
if (thread != null)
{
thread.Suspend();
}

//Continue
if (thread != null)
{
thread.Resume();
}

//Alive
if (thread != null)
{
    if (thread.IsAlive)
    {
     thread.Abort();
    }    
}
```

Or you can use timer....

Comment: Can you change this code to support cooperative cancellation?  You should avoid thread abort, see the links on this answer for why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421389/is-this-thread-abort-normal-and-safe/421445#421445