# C# Threading: How to open main form after thread is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

Forgive me if this question is a duplicate of others, I probably do not know how to word out my problem correctly that's why I could not find the appropriate answer.

I have a winforms C# application with multiple forms. My main form is a login form, prior to it is a splash screen which loads first. My problem is that whenever I click logout, I want it to return to the login screen. However, the splash screen loads and does not open the login form anymore.

I suspect that this is because I started a new thread to be able to close the mainform and open the next form? I read it somewhere that I have to do that because an error occurs when merely using main.close() and form1.show(). Help?

**SPLASH SCREEN CODE**

```
public SplashScreen()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Increment(1);
    if (progressBar1.Value == 100) timer1.Stop();
}
```

**LOGIN START**

```
public LOGIN()
{
   Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashScreen));
   t.Start();
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
   InitializeComponent();
   t.Abort();
}

public void SplashScreen()
{
   Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
}
```

**LOGIN EXIT** (Redirected to user's home page)

```
public static void OpenHomeAdmin() // new thread to open home ADMIN
{
    Application.Run(new Home_Admin());
}

if (usertype == "UT1") //admin rights
{
     //GET LOGGED USER
      Home_Admin homeAdmin = new Home_Admin();
      homeAdmin.SetUsername(username);

      this.Close();
      System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(OpenHomeAdmin));
      t.Start();
 }
```

Comment: `Application.Run(Form)` is used to run a new application on the current thread. Is that your intention? Are you just trying to display new forms?

Comment: @mhornfeck I just want to close my main form and then open another form.

Comment: Can you post the code that handles the click event to Logout?

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same requirement and I wrote the following Code!

In **Program.cs** under Main()

```
Application.Run(new Splash()); //Splash Screen if u wanna run BEFORE Login Form

/*Showing Login Form Before Entering the Main Form [Authentication]*/

login f1 = new login();
DialogResult dr = f1.ShowDialog();
if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
{             
  Application.Run(new Splash()); //Splash Screen if u wanna run AFTER Login Form
  Application.Run(new Home_Admin());
}
else
{
  Application.Exit();
}
```

in **Login Form** - After satisfying the authentication, write the following code

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

This will close your Login Form and get back to Program.cs, then will load your Home_Admin.

in **Home_Admin** make a Logout button and write the following code in click_event

```
this.Close();
login f1=new login();
f1.Show();
```

now u ll be logged out and u ll be back to login screen.

**Note:** Dont use this.Close(); in Main Form, this may exit your application. U can use this.Hide(); in such a chase.

Hope this ll help U.
Try this and Get back with your Comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to start a new Thread in order to open/close your forms. Try the following code instead:

```
if (usertype == "UT1") //admin rights
{
     //GET LOGGED USER
      Home_Admin homeAdmin = new Home_Admin();
      homeAdmin.SetUsername(username);

      this.Hide();
      homeAdmin.Show();
 }
```

Note that `Form.Close()` will dispose the Form object, meaning that all resources created within the object are closed as well. [Read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx). `Form.Hide()` will alternatively hide the form from the user's view.

Comment: My splash screen does not show up anymore if I do this. Is my implementation of my splash screen incorrect too? I used threading for it :|

Comment: I don't think that's a good way to do it. [Use Thread.Abort() only as a last resort](http://stackoverflow.com/q/421389/213159). I would use a Timer in the SplashScreen form that closes the form after 5 seconds.