# Any cycle, until another button is pressed C#

Tags: c#, cycle

Is there any way to do any cycle and break it until another button in 
the WinForms is pressed ?

```
do
        {
            //Action
        } while ("Button Stop is pressed");
```

Comment: The right way of doing this: ["Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The best way that you can do this without blocking the gui is to make use of threads, for instance:

```
Thread t = new Thread (delegate() {
   while(true) {
     What you want to happen inside the loop in here;
     Thread.Sleep(500); // this is useful for keeping the headroom of the CPU
   }
});
```

Start the Thread this way:

```
t.Start();
```

When the stop button is pressed abort the thread this way:

```
t.Abort();
```

This keeps the gui alive.

Comment: @user3363472: You are very welcome, you can accept this (or other) answer if you'd like to

Comment: -1 for `Thread.Abort`, it's a terrible way of terminating a thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421389/is-this-thread-abort-normal-and-safe

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible cases:

1-You are running that loop in the main thread, then the answer is no, if you block the main thread events will not fire and can't catch button click.

2-You are running that loop in a worker thread, in this case you can create a boolean outside the function set to true, check this boolean in your loop and set it to false in the click event of your button.